# How to share Data b/w 2 HTML pages using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in Web based application development. I have a requirement to develop a Pocket IE based application (for WinMobile 6.5 based device) which receives data from device at one HTML page (say MainPage.html) and to show the same user has to switch to another page (say DataPage.html) (as size constraints of the device display). 
I wrote a javascript which receives this huge data and store it in an object. Same Java script I am adding in DataPage.html. But while accessing that data object I am getting as null. It seems as soon as I switch from MainPage.html to DataPage.html, javascript is loaded in new context instead of old context loaded, hence not able to share the data object.
Can anybody help me how should I design this?

Comment: do you have a server backend or just plain html files?

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of these:

- cookies
- query string variables
- a serverside language

What's best depends on how much and what kind of data you have.

I'm not familiar with WinMobile 6.5, but I assume html5's sessionStorage and localStorage are not supported.